# How to log out of Google after app data has been cleared?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

So I am using FirebaseUI Auth in my app to provide logins from Google and Facebook. I have setup the standard `SharedPreferences` to check if app data has been cleared and if it has been, log out of both Firebase and the provider (as instructed in the docs). Logging out of Facebook is pretty straight forward :-

`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`

Now as for Google the way to do it is :-

`Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);`

The problem with this code is I have no idea from where to get `mGoogleApiClient` ie `GoogleSignInClient` object. Since the data is cleared I can't save it either using `SharedPreferences` when creating the builder.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getResources().getString(R.string.google_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

For Signout use below code

```
mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (googleApiClient.isConnected())
   Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient);

 //where googleApiClient is object of GoogleApiClient.
```

Comment: My mistake, I updated the question. I still don't know where do I get the object.

Comment: No need to logout google, all login credentials and data of third party sdk get removed once you clear the data , or uninstall the the app..

Comment: Are you sure about that because if that is the case its a huge relief.

Comment: Yes , you can try. Login from Google, clear data then see if app forces you to login then my answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line where you want to logout in your app.

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`

Comment: I want to log out of the provider, not just Firebase.

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' //add this in your gradle dependencies  and then create the instance of "private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;" in your java file .

Comment: mGoogleSignInClient.signOut() // for the final result use this.